# Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1] sendmail

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail, localhost

если пишу в консоле `sendmail -f mydomen@mail.ru -v mymail@mail.ru`

Получаю

```
Connecting to [127.0.0.1] via relay...
Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]
```

В файле /etc/mail/access
Есть строчка

```
Connect:localhost               RELAY
```

в хостах прописано `127.0.0.1 localhost`

Если подключится telnet`ом к внешниму ip на 25 порт, то всё работает и письма отправляются. А сам себя сервер не видит. Почему?

Comment: Have you changed `relay` mailer definition?  It may be configured to use non default port.

Comment: @AnFi no, only external ip was registered in My settings, thx.